# It's possible to avoid overload on a Mysql slave by slowing down replication?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a slave on a machine less powerful than the the master (8CPU/8GB on the master, 2CPU/4GB on the slave, MySQL 5.7).

Replication is binlog ROW based

As the db is increasing on the master, the slave started to overload the CPU slightly.

I wonder if it's possible to "slow down" the ingestion of binlogs on the slave in order to delay the unavoidable increase of power on the slave machine.

A small lag would not be a problem in my case.

Comment: what MySQL version are you running? Do all your tables have primary keys? Are you talking electrical power overload? What problem are you avoiding?

Comment: I edited a little, I thought was more of a general question. I'm talking about CPU overload on the slave, that has less resources than the master. The problem I'm avoiding is CPU overload on the slave while the master is still good. I don't want to pay for a machine equally powerful on the slave replica as It's only an emergency failover

Comment: Additional information request from your SLAVE server. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your SLAVE MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for SLAVE server tuning analysis.

Comment: I do not see any problem of swamping the CPU on the Slave while it is "catching up".  Is it swamping one CPU or both?  Or is it I/O-bound?

Comment: [binlog_row_image](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_row_image) being `minimal` or `blob` may reduce IO (and a little CPU). There's no harm running the CPU at maximum. As an emergency fail-over its going to be under-spec if used.